# Nested aggregation binding and access parent properties

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have this JSON data:

```json
oDC = [
   {
      "DC_GROUP":"TEST_DC_GROUP",
      "COUNT":0,
      "MULTIPLE_DATA_COLLECT":"false",
      "USERREF":"UserBO:SEA1,EVERTN",
      "STATUS_OP":"IN_WORK",
      "STATUS_SS":"READY",
      "PARAMS":[
         {
            "PROMPT":"CAPTURE",
            "DATA_TYPE":"N",
            "visible":false
         },
         {
            "PROMPT":"DEFAULT TEXT",
            "DATA_TYPE":"T",
            "visible":true
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Saved in a property called "dataCollection" in a model called "viewModel"

```js
let oView = this.getView();
let oModel = oView.getModel("viewModel");
oModel.setProperty("/dataCollection", oDC);
```

And this is an extract of my XML View

```xml
<IconTabBar id="IconTabBarDC" items="{viewModel>/dataCollection}" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
    <items>
        <IconTabFilter text="{viewModel>DC_GROUP}" key="{viewModel>DC_GROUP}">
            <Title 
                text="{viewModel>DC_GROUP}" 
                wrapping="true" 
                titleStyle="H4" 
                level="H4" 
                class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"/>
            <List 
                id="idDataCollect" 
                width="40%" 
                mode="None" 
                updateFinished="handleConstraints" 
                headerText="" 
                items="{path: 'viewModel>PARAMS', templateShareable:false}">
                <items>
                    <CustomListItem visible="{viewModel>visible}">
                        <HBox 
                            alignItems="Center" 
                            justifyContent="SpaceBetween" 
                            class="sapUiTinyMargin">
                            <Label text="{viewModel>PROMPT}" wrapping="true"/>
                            <Input 
                                type="Number" 
                                enabled="{
                                    parts: [
                                        { path: 'viewModel>/STATUS_OP' },
                                        { path: 'viewModel>/COUNT' },
                                        { path: 'viewModel>/MULTIPLE_DATA_COLLECT' },
                                        { path: 'viewModel>/STATUS_SS' }
                                    ],
                                    formatter: '.formatter.isDCParamEnabled'
                                }" 
                                required="{viewModel>visible}"
                                change=".changeNumParam"/>
                        </HBox>
                    </CustomListItem>
                </items>
            </List>
        </IconTabFilter>
    </items>
</IconTabBar>
```

My issue is that the in inner aggregation (PARAMS) I cannot access the fields from the outer aggregation (/dataCollection).

I tried in all these formats, with no success:

```
'viewModel>STATUS_OP'
'viewModel>/STATUS_OP'
'viewModel>dataCollection/STATUS_OP'
'viewModel>/dataCollection/STATUS_OP'
```

The fields inside PARAMS work fine
for example {viewModel>PROMPT}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dataCollection is an array. PARAMS is also an array.

Your first IconTabbarFilter is `dataCollection/0`/.
Your first CustomListItem is `dataCollection/0/PARAMS/0`.

The problem is that you need the dataCollection index in your PARAMS array to know which element you are in. You have to modify your dataCollection with a script like this:

```js
var oDC = [{
  "DC_GROUP": "TEST_DC_GROUP",
  "COUNT": 0,
  "MULTIPLE_DATA_COLLECT": "false",
  "USERREF": "UserBO:SEA1,EVERTN",
  "STATUS_OP": "IN_WORK",
  "STATUS_SS": "READY",
  "PARAMS": [{
      "PROMPT": "CAPTURE",
      "DATA_TYPE": "N",
      "visible": false
    },
    {
      "PROMPT": "DEFAULT TEXT",
      "DATA_TYPE": "T",
      "visible": true
    }
  ]
}];

var aTransferProperties = ["MULTIPLE_DATA_COLLECT", "STATUS_SS", "STATUS_OP", "COUNT"];


for(var i = 0; i < oDC.length; i++){ //Loop oDC array with objects
  for(key in oDC[i]){ //Loop oDC array object properties
    if (aTransferProperties.indexOf(key) > -1) { //if the key is needed in child 

       for(var j = 0; j <  oDC[i].PARAMS.length; j++){ //Loop PARAMS
             oDC[i].PARAMS[j][key] = oDC[i][key]; //insert key/value from parent in every child
           }      
           delete oDC[i][key]; //optional Delete the key/value from parent
        }
   }
}

console.log(oDC);
```

Comment: This was my solution so far, to copy the attributes I needed to the inner arrays (I also need those atributes in the outer arrays). Not sure it is the best way of doing it, I feel there is some other way. As this actually solves the issue, I will mark it as accepted answer. thanks!